# Personalización de ChoiceField en Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Estoy personalizando unos `ChoiceField` de un formulario que hice con Django 1.9, porque los labels del campo posterior a cada `ChoiceField` salen adjuntos a los `ChoiceField`.

También quise ponerles `verbose_name` y atributos (usando Widgets) pero Python me arroja error:

Este es mi `ChoiceField` actual que quiero personalizar:

```
Marca = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MARCA_CHOICES)
```

Esta es la sintaxis que creo que debería tener si quiero personalizarlo:

```
Marca = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MARCA_CHOICES, 
        verbose_name='Marca de auto', 
        widget=forms.ChoiceInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-group form-control control-label'}))
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Qué otros atributos se le pueden aplicar a `ChoiceField` en caso de ser posible?

Ahora al editar siguiendo los pasos de César, recibo el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x031E4070>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\utils
\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
 checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
checks\urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
checks\urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\utils
  \functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns",        self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\utils
\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
   File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\core\
urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\vehilometro\vehilometro\urls.p
y", line 20, in <module>
    from vehiapp.views import index
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\vehilometro\vehiapp\views.py",
 line 17, in <module>
    from .forms import CriterioForm, ContactoForm
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\vehilometro\vehiapp\forms.py",
 line 18, in <module>
    class CriterioForm(forms.Form):
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\vehilometro\vehiapp\forms.py",
 line 19, in CriterioForm
    Marca = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MARCA_CHOICES,     widget=forms.widgets.Choice
Input)
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\forms
\fields.py", line 799, in __init__
     initial=initial, help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\User\Envs\vehilometro\lib\site-packages\django\forms
\fields.py", line 105, in __init__
    widget = widget()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Podrías añadir el Traceback del error a la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

No has especificado el error pero según veo en tu código lo más probable es que sea en esta parte:

```
widget=forms.ChoiceInput(..)
```

Ya que `ChoiceInput` no es parte del módulo `forms` sino del módulo [`widgets`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L608). Debería ser algo así:

```
widget=forms.widgets.ChoiceInput(..)
```

Aunque no creo que `ChoiceInput` sea lo que estés buscando como Widget para un `ChoiceField`.

Por otro lado, `verbose_name` no es un atributo permitido en los campos de formularios. La clase `Field` toma por defecto los campos indicados en la documentación en la entrada [Core field arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#core-field-arguments). Entonces, en vez de `verbose_name` tienes que usar `label`:

```
marca = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=MARCA_CHOICES, 
    label='Marca de auto'
)
```

Algo más, si quieres agregar atributos al Widget no es necesario reemplazarlo, puedes sobreescribir el método `__init__` del formulario para agregar nuevos atributos a tu campo:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    marca = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=MARCA_CHOICES, 
        label='Marca de auto'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['marca'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-group form-control control-label'
        }
```

El atributo [`Widget.attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) del Widget es un diccionario que contiene atributos HTML así que es posible pasarle cosas como:

```
self.fields['foo'].widget.attrs = {
    'class': 'a b c',
    'size': '100',
    'data-bar': 'barbar',
    'title': 'Algo',
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo hice como me decías, pero sigo recibiendo error, actualizaré la pregunta con el traceback que recibo

Comment: Amigo César, deja preguntas para los iniciados jajaja. @Ryuuko, actualiza tu pregunta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Veo tres cosas: la primera es que en un campo form debes usar `label` y en vez de `verbose_name` (este es para el modelo), la segunda es que no existe el widget `forms.ChoiceInput`, seguramente es `forms.Select` y la tercera es que en el atributo class solo va 'form-control' porque la clase `form-group` es usada para el contenedor (div) y `control-label` es para el label, si quieres personalizar el estilo te recomiendo [Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), es una librería muy fácil de usar y puedes usar bootstrap. El código final quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Marca = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MARCA_CHOICES, 
        label='Marca de auto', 
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control'}))
```